# Non sensitive search in SORM with PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, sql-like, sorm

How to do non sensitive search in database using SORM and PostgreSQL?
I tried `whereLike`:

```
DB.query[User].whereLike("fullname", "%" + term + "%").fetch()
```

This performs a case sensitive search. PostreSQL supports `ILIKE` operator, but didn't find `ILIKE` function in SORM DSL API.

I tried with `whereRegex` too:

```
DB.query[User].whereRegex("fullname", term).fetch()
```

This returns an error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "REGEXP"
```

[Acording](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html) to documentation PostgreSQL doesn't use the `REGEXP` operator, it uses a ~ (tilda) operator. As I understand this causes an error. I would like to perform something like this with regexp:

```
SELECT "fullname" FROM "user" WHERE "fullname" ~ 'john';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The regex not working in Postgres was a bug, which is now fixed in release 0.3.17. Thanks for spotting that.

Concerning the case-sensitiveness, looks like Postgres uses a different operator for regexes as well. Hmmm. Looks like there is no way to do this with Postgres currently. Introduction of appropriate operators will be required for SORM, contribution is welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added IgnoreCaseLike operator that make ILIKE in PostgreSQL database and create a pull request on GitHub. I will apreciate if you will review it and accept if code is ok, I really need it in my current project :) Meantime I found tricky to create a IgnoreCaseLike that will work on all databases, cause PostgreSQL uses ILIKE, Mysql uses LIKE that is non sensitive by default, H2 and HSQLDB use lower/upper functions to ignore case in search.